# Cygwin g++ doesn't recognize "fixed" as part of the STD library

Tags: c++, cygwin, fixed

I'm an amateur with C++ and I'm learning to compile by command line using g++. I downloaded and installed Cygwin and I can't get this code to work:

```
// setprecision example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::fixed
#include <iomanip>      // std::setprecision

int main () {
  double f =3.14159;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << '\n';
  std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << f << '\n';
  std::cout << std::fixed;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << '\n';
  std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << f << '\n';
return 0;
```

}

But when I run the console

```
g++ -c Test.cpp
```

I get the error:

```
Test.cpp: In function `int main()':
Test.cpp:9: undeclared variable `fixed' (first use here)
```

Can anyone explain where the error comes from and how I can fix it? I tried

```
#include <ios>
```

at the top of my program but it tells me that the file/directory can't be found. In the include\g++\ subfolder of my Cygnus program I have an iomanip.h and iostream file but no ios file.

Answer (score 4):

You need `#include <ios>`. `iostream` is not required to include very much, and needn't declare `fixed`.

Comment: That's a pity. It would be better IMHO if it were either *required* to declare `fixed` or *forbidden* to do so. Leaving it up to each implementation makes it needlessly difficult to write portable code.

Comment: True, although getting the detail right would be complex and might over-constrain implementors. There's been a lot of work recently in gcc's library to minimise what each header drags in, but it's not trivial.